# C# Loop Through Subclasses

Tags: c#, class, loops, inheritance

Very new to C# so forgive me if this is a silly question.

If I have a base class called Validator, and a number of classes which inherit from this class such as validateFirstname, validateSecondname etc... is it possible to write a method which will loop through each of these subclasses and instantiate each?

Something along the lines of

```
public class loadValidators
{
  public loadValidators()
  {
   foreach (subclass in class)
     {
       // instantiate class here
     }
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var validator_type = typeof (Validator);

var sub_validator_types = 
    validator_type
    .Assembly
    .DefinedTypes
    .Where(x => validator_type.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x != validator_type)
    .ToList();


foreach (var sub_validator_type in sub_validator_types)
{
    Validator sub_validator = (Validator)Activator.CreateInstance(sub_validator_type);
}
```

This code assumes that all the sub classes live in the same assembly/project as the Validator class.

Also, it assumes that each of the subclasses have a public parameterless constructor.

Please note that I would not recommend this approach.

Instead you should do something like this to solve your problem (of modeling/using multiple validators):

```
public interface IValidator
{
    bool Validate(SomeObject something);
}

public class FirstNameValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool Validate(SomeObject something)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class LastNameValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool Validate(SomeObject something)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class CompositeValidator : IValidator
{
    private readonly IValidator[] m_Validators;

    public CompositeValidator(params IValidator[] validators)
    {
        m_Validators = validators;
    }

    public bool Validate(SomeObject something)
    {
        foreach (IValidator validator in m_Validators)
        {
            if (!validator.Validate(something))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The `CompositeValidator` wraps multiple validators and knows how to validate objects using those validators.

You can use it like this:

```
var composite_validator = new CompositeValidator(new FirstNameValidator() , new LastNameValidator());

composite_validator.Validate(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So what I have is very similar to the second solution you provided (as I'm following a tutorial). The reason I was wondering if it was possible to create the validations via loop, was to be able to write a new validator, and have it automatically included in the composite_validator. So, instead of having to pass the new validator into the params of composite validator every time i write a new one, i could run the loadValidators function, which instantness all the validators, adds them to a list, then passes this list to the params of composite_validator.

Comment: Or is that a terrible idea? so instead of composite_validator(new v1(), new v2(), new v3() etc..) i could just go loadValidators(), then composite_validator(person).

Comment: I would go with `composite_validator(new v1(), new v2(), new v3() etc..)`. This is how you compose your application in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)